# Is it possible to apply two different displacement maps to two different regions of a mesh in Blender?

Tags: uv, displacement

My attempt to accomplish this was to create 2 separate UV maps that only map the vertices in the region I want to apply the displacement maps to. Then I apply 2 different displacement modifiers and use one UV map for each. This did not work as expected. Here is what I did specifically:

1. Create a mesh. In my example I am using a simple ring model made by using a smaller oval curve as the bevel object for a larger circle curve. After increasing the Resolution Preview I then convert this object to a mesh.

[image]

2. Delete existing UV map
3. Select first subset of vertices for one of the displacement map. Generate new UV map with `UV > Cylinder Projection`. Direction should be align to object and select Scale to Bounds

[image]

4. Select the next subset of vertices. Create a new UV map (Object data properties > UV Maps > Plus button), and then generate the new map with a Cylinder Projection again

[image]

5. Create 2 displacement modifiers with the coordinates set to UV and the 2 different UV maps selected. These are the displacement maps I've used and the resulting mesh

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

This almost works as I expect. Each displacement map is in the area I want it to be, but the outer surface has both displacement maps applied. I noticed when I created the second map, the original map's vertices seemed to be under the new map. However I am not able to delete these. I am assuming this is the root of the problem, but I don't know how to solve it.

Please let me know if I need to supply additional information

Comment: Did you try to additionally use vertex groups for your displace modifiers? Just the ones you need? Should be pretty much the same as you selected for the UV map, maybe that helps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have already created two vertex groups, `OutsideGroup` and `InsideGroup`, and used them for the UV Maps.  You only need one more step: Add the appropriate vertex group to the *Vertex Group* field of the correct displacement modifier.

Comment: This did work for me. Do you know why it’s necessary? When I create the second UV Map why do the original vertices populate it and how do it get rid of them?

Comment: No I don't.  You'd think the UV Map would be sufficient, but the modifier works on the entire object unless you give it a vertex group.